# Remove command-prompt in D?

Tags: d, command-prompt, platform-independent

I'm writing an SDL app in D (therefore I'd like to maintain a high amount of platform-independence), and I'm looking for a way to stop the command prompt opening up release builds. How does one do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Call DMD with the option `-L-Subsystem:Windows`.

Just make sure that your `main` gets changed to `WinMain`, with the appropriate arguments.

Comment: Again, I'd like a platform-independent way of doing this.

Comment: @RobotGymnast: I'm not sure you can, because native GUI apps don't have a standardized method of starting up, AFAIK.

Comment: `version(Windows)`. Linux and MacOSX don't have separate commandline/GUI modes.

Comment: Are you sure you need to change main to WinMain?  I've never done that, and GUI still works.

Comment: Whoa, what? I've always used WinMain (I use Visual D's templates)... that's funny.

Comment: There's no need to switch to WinMain, just -L/su:windows:4 is enough.

Answer (score 0):

I did exactly this https://bitbucket.org/ponce/vibrant/src/032e61352ad9/trunk/vibrant/vibrant.d (public domain)